# Emtpy workflow initiation form when starting a worflow to publish a major version

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, publishing-page, approval

I have a problem with my pages library publishing approval workflow.
My Workflow inititation form will only show for the site collection administrator.
I have tried to give the "ordinary" user the "Full Control" permission, but still the workflow initiation form only shows for my administrator. 
Anyone had this problem ?
[image]

[image]